# Необходимо добавить библиотеку frescoimageviewer в android-проект

Tags: android, gradle

Пытаюсь добавить зависимость

```
implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
```

в свой проект, срывается на сборке:

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/stfalcon/frescoimageviewer/0.5.0/frescoimageviewer-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так и как ее подключить?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего из за того что у вас версия gradle 7 а maven был удален в Gradle 7.0, посмотрите этот [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599438/gradle-7-and-jitpack-io-runs-into-error-during-publish)!